# How many amps does a pi with 11 sensors need?

Tags: pi-3, power-supply, power-management

I have received so much support from this community by reading already answered questions. But now I got one that hasn't been asked yet. I have nearly a dozen sensors connected to my pi 3 so it's only natural I should be concerned about supplying adequate power to the pi.

My question is: how many amps should I be feeding the pi considering that I got six 5v and five 3v sensors connected?

Comment: Depends on the sensors. A gas sensor or similar can draw a couple of hundred milliamps while a temperature or humidity sensor might have a negligible current draw...

Comment: 1 5v fan, 1 PIR, 
1mq5,
1dth11,
2 active laser diode, 1 relay switch, 1 tilt switch, 1 buzzer, 1 16x2 char LCD, 3 Leds.

Comment: The Pi draws current as needed.  You don't actively "feed" it. Not clear if that's a simple misuse of terms or if it represents a genuine misunderstanding on your side.

Comment: OK.. Actually what I mean by 'feed' is how many amps should the power adapter powering the pi be considering the plethora of sensors. 2amps? 3amps?

Answer (score 0):

I'd assume the the following:

- 5v fan - 100 mA
- PIR - 5 mA
- MQ5 - 5 mA
- DHT11 - 5 mA
- Active laser diode - 16 mA x 2 - 32 mA
- relay switch - 1 mA
- tilt switch - 1 mA
- buzzer - 50 mA
- 16x2 char LCD - 10 mA
- LEDs - 8 mA x 3 - 24 mA

Comment: Will a 5v 2 Amps charger be enough?

Comment: I would be surprised if it wasn't.  The Pi should need about an amp for itself.  There should be plenty left over for your peripherals and sensors.

Comment: Great. I'm doing it right then. However, I noticed that the LCD would sometimes pulsate with the buzzer when it went off.

Comment: I am guessing about how much the various components use, it wouldn't be a surprise if the buzzer uses more than I had thought.